# program crashes after assigning values to array elements

Tags: c++, arrays, qt

I have a class with name setaddress containing a structure that contains a 2D array:`int WaterMeterIDs[20][2];`

```
namespace Ui {
class SetAddress;
}

class SetAddress : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    struct AddressList{
        int WaterMeterIDs[20][2];
    };
    explicit SetAddress(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~SetAddress();
    etc...
private:
    Ui::SetAddress *ui;
    AddressList m_address;
```

I want to save my data that is in a qtablewidget cells using this commands
in my .cpp file:

```
void SetAddress::on_pushButton_apply_clicked()
{
    int rowscount = ui->tableWidget->rowCount();
//rowscount is always less than 20
    for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
        for(int i = 0; i < rowscount; i++){
            if(ui->tableWidget->item(i,j) != 0x0 ){//if cell is not empty
                 m_address.WaterMeterIDs[i][j] = ui->tableWidget->item(i,j)->text().toInt();//convert data to int and put it in array
                 qDebug()<<m_address.WaterMeterIDs[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when I click on apply button the program works good(I can see array elements using qDebug()).
but after I pressed the apply button if I press any other key even the close button(or even if I want to resize the window) program crashes!

Comment: can you run your program under _valgrind_ to check the memory accesses ?

Comment: run it in debugger and look there it hangs and what happens...

Comment: r u sure the tableWidget has 2 cols and 20 rows?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツyes (has less than 20 rows)

Comment: can you see any mistake in my code?

Answer (score 3):

> can you see any mistake in my code?

Even if you are sure that your indexes are within range, there's nothing in the code you've shown us that makes really sure that's the case, so I'd replace your array with this:

```
#include <array>

class AddressList{
    std::array<std::array<int, 2>, 20> WaterMeterIDs;

public:
    inline constexpr int& at(size_t row, size_t col) {
        return WaterMeterIDs.at(row).at(col);
    }

    inline constexpr int const& at(size_t row, size_t col) const {
        return WaterMeterIDs.at(row).at(col);
    }
};
```

Then access the array via the `at()` function:

```
// set value
m_address.at(i,j) = ...

// log value
qDebug() << m_address.at(i,j);
```

That should make you sure that nothing slipped through the cracks regarding your 2D array.

And I'd check that `ui->tableWidget->columnCount() >= 2` before the loop, just to rule that out too:

```
int colcount = std::min(2, ui->tableWidget->columnCount());
for(int j = 0; j < colcount; ++j) {
   ...
```

Comment: why not just `WaterMeterIDs.at(row).at(col)`?

Comment: @Caleth I suspected it may be used in more places so it's just to make it easier to convert - and when/if OP wants the timeconsuming check gone, he can just comment out `check_range` and leave the code as is. Edit: Ah, I think you meant, why I didn't use it in `check_range`?`Good question :-)

Comment: I'd be suspicious of an `at` method that didn't throw. You'd want some other name for unchecked access, e.g. `int& operator()(size_t, size_t)` or `std::array<2, int>& operator[](size_t)` or `int& operator[](index_t)`

Comment: I'm very confused. I want to find my mistake in my code to prevent repeating that.

Comment: @reza moslemi The code you've shown doesn't show any mistakes that I can see, other than not checking boundaries. Did you try with the suggestions I made?

Comment: my code wasn't wrong. I deleted build folder and rebuilt the program and now it doesn't crash

Comment: Ok, that's not good. The build dependencies are probably broken somehow so that not all files that needed to be recompiled actually were. If you change one header file in the project and then recompile, will all `.cpp` files that are including that header (directly or indirectly) be recompiled? Try that for all headers.